# How to completely remove the margin of a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, microsoft-word-2016, margins

So I'm trying to design a Christmas letter and I just can't figure out how to *truly* remove the margin at the top and bottom. It's technically probably not a margin.

I've already set the margin in the page setup to 0. I just don't have any idea how to fix this.

Page setup:

[image: Page setup]

Print Preview:
[image: Print preview]

Actual document within word where it looks fine:
[image: Actual document within word where it looks fine]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limiting factor is your printer, not Word. It seems your printer does not support borderless printing and that's also suggested by the technical specifications on the Dell website.

Compare the following: Selecting my printer will yield similar results to your situation:
[Real Printer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWhPU.png)

Selecting a PDF "printer" there are no borders:
[PDF Printer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7eeO.png)

Comment: This might be a naive question. But if I export it to PDF without borders - will I be able to print it without a white border?

Comment: No. Again, *the limiting factor is your printer, not Word*.

Comment: Just to add to this: There exist printers that can do borderless printing, even for home use. I don't want to advertise any model here, but some devices are quite affordable. In any case, your local copy shop should be able to print borderless if you provide them a borderless PDF.

Comment: @hanjo Is there a keyword I can use to find a printer that'd support the borderless printing? I'm kinda stuck with the "borderless" keyword.

Comment: English isn't my native language, but "borderless" seems to be the right word. I have found this for printers of the HP ENVY series.

Answer (score 0):

As Hanjo says, the limit isn't Word, it's your printer. Whatever prints to a printer that can't do edge to edge printing will end up adding a strip at the top and bottom (and/or left and right hand edge).

After having said that, I have a possible solution: Can you buy legal paper, print 'long' and then just trip the paper down? You could even print "cutting" lines. Buying a paper cutter would be cheaper than buying a whole new printer, and useful for other things too :)